# Examples where makeKeyAndVisible is not required for UIWindow

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwindow

I was wondering in all iOS applications we have to write makeKeyAndVisible for our UIWindow object. So is there a example where we dont want our application to makeKeyAndVisible.

If we always require it for any application, then why dint apple automatically write it for us, like they did for @synthesize as part of iOS 6?

Comment: I dont use it when I develop storyboard apps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An app can have more than one window. The call to `makeKeyAndVisible` is used to specify which one is current.

Despite the fact that most apps only have one window, there is no way to assume that your primary window is to be the key window. Therefore you must explicitly call `makeKeyAndVisible`.

Answer (score 11):

Apple handles makeKeyAndVisible automatically with storyboards

With storyboards, iOS performs the following steps:

- It instantiates a window for you.
- It loads the main storyboard and instantiates its initial view controller.
- It assigns the new view controller to the window’s rootViewController property and then makes the window visible on the screen.

Comment: "So you don't have to explicitly use makeKeyAndVisible anymore" - only true if you are using storyboards. Not everyone uses storyboards or even Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

If you use storyboard to launch your app it's not required to call **makeKeyAndVisible**.

You can try to create a new project in Xcode 6. The project is not using **makeKeyAndVisible**, and you will get nil if you try to get keyWindow.